# How to scaffold for NativeScript services

Tags: design-patterns, nativescript

I am proposing to do is to have a separate folder which will contain 'services'. This would be for calls out to various REST APIs. Below is the pattern I'm thinking of using. Does this break any conventions of NativeScript or is it even good practice? The services could be called from other folders within the app so I am trying to keep things DRY.

```
app.js // The main app file, loads /items/items_list/items_list.xml
          as first screen of the app.

/services
  /parts
     get_parts.js // Lets say this would be a http service, called from
                     either /items or /jobs, or even anywhere else
                     within the app.

/items
  /items_list
    item_list.css
    item_list.xml
    item_list.js
    ...
/jobs
  /jobs_list
    jobs_list.css
    jobs_list.xml
    jobs_list.js
    ...
```

The names are made up for the purposes of the question so hopefully it still makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its nice to have a separate folder structire for the services - Nativescript is using MVVM pattern and structurally it's really a good idea to have good architecture for your app especially if your app is going to grow.
You can take a look at the example below for both structural design and automatization with using grunt tasks.

http://blog.cendekiapp.com/2015/03/12/generate-mvvm-nativescript-folder-structure-with-grunt/#

It's really simple to recreate and once set will allow you to desing big application structure for seconds.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer. My question might have been a little vague as StephenFeather suggests. This is the answer I was looking for. I've visited that link and that confirms that I'm on the right track for my NativeScript project. Thanks to both of you for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

This is very much a question seeking an opinionated versus technical answer.

Technical: 
no, it shouldn't break anything within NativeScript

Opinionated: 
However, on android, your app can run actual background 'services', so does the choice of 'services' conflict with native terminology?

In another context, 'services' may mean the actions that a technician may perform for an end user?

I'm guessing that you like the term 'services' because these will be your calls TO a web service, not because they are actually 'services'.  Naming is often subjective, but I'd try to name things for what they 'are' or 'do' rather than what they communicate 'with'. In this case, those files would be more an ApiClient library. During a quick browse of the project, would another dev know that this directory contained all the wrapped api calls, etc?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I guess there is a opinion/technical fuzziness there. I guess I just wanted to ensure I didn't do anything 'incorrectly' but I take your point. Also, very good point about the term 'services'. I am going to use something more descriptive using 'api' or 'remoteServices' or 'restServices'. Thanks for the input.